# Extract part of an XML file as plain text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Seems like this should be easy, but ...

I'm trying to use XSLT to extract part of an XML file as plain text, throwing away the rest.

So from sample input like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?oxygen RNGSchema="http://segonku.unl.edu/teianalytics/TEIAnalytics.rng"
                        type="xml"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" n="Wright2-0034.sgml.xml">
   <teiHeader type="text">
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>Header Title</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>Published</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Sourced</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
   </teiHeader>
   <text>
      <front>
      </front>
      <body>
         <head>THE TITLE</head>
         <div type="chapter" part="N" org="uniform" sample="complete">
            <head>CHAPTER I</head>
            <p>Some text.</p>
         </div>
      </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

... I'm trying to get just the text contained within the `<body>` tags and all their children. The desired output in this case is:

```
THE TITLE
CHAPTER I
Some text.
```

Potential complication: `<body>` can also exist in the `<front>` matter and/or in the `<teiHeader>`, so what I really need is the children of `<body>` if and only if that tag is a child of `<text>` and of `<TEI>`.

I've tried really simple XSL like this ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/TEI/text/body">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... but it gives me plain text of everything in the file, not just the `<body>` elements.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the problem and for a complete, short and easy solution.

Comment: Are you aware of the troubles you are going to encounter for _inline_ elements, tables and lists? Do you need those to be managed?

Comment: @empo Good point. Fortunately not one I need to worry about for my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've tried really simple XSL like this
>   ...
>
> ...
>
> ```
>      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>  version="1.0">
>          <xsl:output method="text"/>
>          <xsl:template match="/TEI/text/body">
>              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
>          </xsl:template>
>      </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```
>
> ... but it gives me plain text of
>   everything in the file, not just the
>   `<body>` elements.

The reason for this is a famous property/feature of XPath (and reason for many thousands similar questions) to consider any unprefixed name as belonging to "no namespace. However, any element in the provided XML document belongs to the namespace: "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" and must be accessed as a node in this namespace.

**Solution**: Define the documents default namespace in the XSLT code (this time with a prefix bound to it) and use the prefix in specifying every name.

**This is one of the simplest and shortest possible transformations** that produces the wanted result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="x:text/x:body//text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" n="Wright2-0034.sgml.xml">
    <teiHeader type="text">
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Header Title</title>
            </titleStmt>
            <publicationStmt>
                <p>Published</p>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <p>Sourced</p>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <text>
        <front>      </front>
        <body>
            <head>THE TITLE</head>
            <div type="chapter" part="N" org="uniform" sample="complete">
                <head>CHAPTER I</head>
                <p>Some text.</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
THE TITLE
CHAPTER I
Some text.
```

Comment: +1 for the good explanation (and correct answer indeed). Notice this approach adds a line break for each text descendant node. This might be unwanted for _inline_ elements or lists inside the `body`. Even if there is no OP mention about that, this is a real common problem when trying to convert HTML-like markup to plain text. Not to mention cases with tables :))

Comment: @empo: The OP wants that each text node starts on a new line in the output -- not that they are concatenated.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, this is perfect. Thanks for the explanation; I'm very glad to know what I was missing with the original attempt. +1 and answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:n="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:for-each select="/n:TEI/n:text/n:body/descendant::*/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

It returns:

```
THE TITLE
CHAPTER I
Some text.
```

Comment: He needs to ensure the /TEI/text/body path, though.

Comment: I would better declare the namespace in the root XSLT element. If you have much more templates you'll get crazy with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching /TEI/text/body//text()

Comment: Sorry mate, this is the wrong advice -- see my answer for explanation.