# Segmentation fault while convering large number of xml files into text

Tags: c, xml, linux

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fin,*fout;
  char dest[80]="/home/vivs/InexCorpusText/";
  char file[30];
  DIR *dir;
  char c,state='1';
  int len;
  struct dirent *ent;
  if((dir=opendir("/home/vivs/InexCorpus"))!=NULL)
  {
    while((ent=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
    {
      if(strcmp(ent->d_name,".") &&
         strcmp(ent->d_name,"..") &&
         strcmp(ent->d_name,".directory"))
      {
        len=strlen(ent->d_name);
        strcpy(file,ent->d_name);
        file[len-3]=file[len-1]='t';
        file[len-2]='x';
        //strcat(source,ent->d_name);
        strcat(dest,file);
        printf("%s\t%s\n",ent->d_name,dest);
        fin=fopen(ent->d_name,"r");
        fout=fopen(dest,"w");
        while((c=fgetc(fin))!=EOF)
        {
          if(c=='<')
          {
            fputc(' ',fout);
            state='0';
          }
          else if(c=='>')
            state='1';
          else if(state=='1')
          {
            if(c!='\n')
            fputc(c,fout);
            if(c=='.')
            {
              c=fgetc(fin);
              if(c==' '||c=='\n'||c=='<')
              {
                fputc('\n',fout);
                ungetc(c,fin);
              }
              else fputc(c,fout);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      close(fin);
      close(fout);
      strcpy(dest,"/home/vivs/InexCorpusText/");
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error in opening directory\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I was trying to convert xml files to text. This code simply remove tags and nothing else.
When i execute this code for around 300 files, it doesn't show any error but when number goes to 500 or more i receive a segmentation fault after processing around 300 files.

Comment: Does your keyboard sport a `<tab>` key?

Comment: Can you be certain that the file names will never be more than 29 characters?  You could overflow `file` otherwise.  Also, you need to check that `fopen` does not return `NULL`.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where, exactly, the error is happening?

Comment: I tried all of these but nothing is helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

At least one reason 'right from the start':

Here is `struct dirent` declaration from man:

```
   On Linux, the dirent structure is defined as follows:

       struct dirent {
           ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
           off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
           unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
           unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                          by all file system types */
           char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
       };
```

You are in trouble on any name longer than 30 (actually 29) chars. Memory overwrite occurs because **file** has only 30 bytes (reserve 1 for '\0' terminator):

```
char file[30];
...
strcpy(file,ent->d_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Roman Nikitchenko. :) .But my file name never exceeds more than 23.

Answer (score 1):

There are two structures within XML that it does not appear that you account for.

1. Attribute contents can contain unescaped `>` characters, which could throw off your count. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue.
2. CDATA sections can contain both `<` and `>` characters as literal text, as long as they do not appear as part of the closing `]]>` string. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-CharData. This could seriously throw off your logic.

Why don't you look in your files to see if any contain the text `CDATA`?

You might want to consider using [xsltproc or libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html); a very simple XSLT transform would give you exactly what you want. See [Extract part of an XML file as plain text using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392890/extract-part-of-an-xml-file-as-plain-text-using-xslt) for such a transform engine.

Comment: That will not cause any problem in my case as after converting it to text i modify it and revert to xml form.BTW thanks lavinio for such useful information. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, another problematic place:

```
len=strlen(ent->d_name);
....
file[len-3]=file[len-1]='t';
file[len-2]='x';
```

Because `d_name` could have less than 3 characters it could again lead to memory overwrite.
You should be careful with functions like `strlen()` and always validate their result.